# How to Navigate to an instance of a UWP page?

Tags: uwp

I use below `way 1` to Navigate to a page called `PageTemplate`(maybe from Page A), and initialize it with `data1`.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageTemplate), data1);
```

And in `PageTemplate`, I use below `way 2` to initialize its page data.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        var data = e.Parameter as DataModel;
        ...
    }
}
```

And next time I may navigate from page B to `PageTemplate` and use `data2` to initialize `PageTemplate`:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageTemplate), data2);
```

**Question 1:**
So finally, `PageTemplate` with `data1` and `PageTemplate` with `data2` are both in navigation cache?

If not, how to achieve it? I mean a same `page template`(page elements and architect are same) with different data in navigation cache simoutinoeously.

**Question 2:**
If we have solution to put same `PageTemplate` with data1/data2 as two different pages in navigation cache, how to navigate to them then?

Comment: Page content and state is not cached unless you set the `NavigationCacheMode` property to `Enabled` or `Required`. You may still navigate to a cached page and change its state in the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

> So finally, PageTemplate with data1 and PageTemplate with data2 are both in navigation cache?

If we navigate with this order(A-->PageTemplate-->B-->PageTemplate), We could make sure PageTemplate with data1 and PageTemplate with data2 are both in navigation stack? And you could get above stack with [`BackStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.backstack) property

> If we have solution to put same PageTemplate with data1/data2 as two different pages in navigation cache, how to navigate to them then?

If you want to process the data1 and data2 type with `PageTemplate` at same time. we need set data1 with the source page's tag and detect the data type in `PageTemplate` then switch to different workflow.

Package the parameter with `Dictionary` that could store the source page tag into key part.

```
var parameter = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameter.Add(nameof(MainPage), data1);
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageTemplate), parameter);
```

**Data Process**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        var data = e.Parameter as Dictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "MainPage":

                    break;
                case "OtherPage":

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```